# Python: Place # in front of several lines

Tags: python, hashtag

After a Windows update I am unable in any Python writing application to place a # in front of several lines
Normally, it is shift + #

Comment: you can kind of emulate that by using docstrings and wrapping multiple lines of code around them

Comment: Looks like your keyboard layout is wrong. You have to correct that in Windows, this is not a Python question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Visual studio Code in windows, it will allow you to comment multiple lines using ctrl + / in any python file.